# Handling PostgreSQL similiar, but not quite duplicate records

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains a number of rows that are duplicated. I can get rid of those with:

```
DELETE FROM files
WHERE id IN (
 SELECT id 
 FROM (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY name, active, filesize, start_timestamp, end_timestamp ORDER BY id) AS rnum
FROM files) t 
WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

This works fine most of the time, however I have a number of rows where the filesize and end_timestamp changes, but all of the remaining data remains the same. What I would like to do is when duplicate records exist change the active attribute of the records with the smallest filesize and end_timestamp to false.

I'm just a having a moment and cant seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Some variation of this ? with f2 as  (  select id, min(filesize) as fs , min(end_timestamp) as et , count(*) from files group by id having count(*) > 1  )
update files as f1 set active = 'f' 
from  f2 where 
f1.id = f2.id and f1.filesize = f2.fs and f1.end_timestamp = f2.et

Comment: You said you are trying to delete, then you said "change ... to false". What exactly do you mean by "change to false"? An UPDATE? Or you actually meant "delete all and keep the one with smallest filesize and end_timestamp"?

Comment: "What I would like to do is when duplicate records exist change the active attribute of the records with the smallest filesize and end_timestamp to false." Deletions would come at a later date once I had confirmed that this has left me with the dataset I am wanting.